# how to make a javascript program that scans a website for a link

Tags: javascript, html, search, hyperlink

I need a program that scans a website for a link. This is what I have so far, but it doesnt  auto click or find the link, it just refreshes the page. Could you guys maybe fix the eroors in the code or tell me how to fix them? btw this code is used for a bot which refreshes nike's twitter feed and then auto-clicks on the link as soon as it appears. the "var shoeName" is what the name of the shoe is. Thanks

```
var shoeName = "Nike Flyknit Max";
var nikestore = "nikestore";
var closeFlag = "no";
var tFunction = "twitterScan()";
var tweet = new Array();
var tweetName = new Array();

function twitterScan() {

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    tweetName[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("fullname js-action-profile-name show-popup-with-id")[0].innerHTML;
    tweet[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("js-tweet-text")[i].innerHTML;

}


//if (document.getElementsByClassName("fullname js-action-profile-name show-popup-with-id")[0].innerHTML;

if (tweet[0].match(shoeName) == shoeName) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-timeline-link")[0].click();
    tFunction = "get outa here";
    shoeName = " 4444  4 456 7 8 456 7 345 7 345  345 3 1 1 133s "; //buffer to jump out of interval loop

} 

else if (tweet[1].match(shoeName) == shoeName) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-timeline-link")[1].click();
    tFunction = "get outa here";
    shoeName = " 4444  4 456 7 8 456 7 345 7 345  345 3 1 1 133s "; //buffer to jump out of interval loop

}

else if (tweet[2].match(shoeName) == shoeName) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-timeline-link")[2].click();
    tFunction = "get outa here";
    shoeName = " 4444  4 456 7 8 456 7 345 7 345  345 3 1 1 133s "; //buffer to  jump out of interval loop

}


else if (tweet[3].match(shoeName) == shoeName) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-timeline-link")[3].click();
    tFunction = "get outa here";
    shoeName = " 4444  4 456 7 8 456 7 345 7 345  345 3 1 1 133s "; //buffer to         jump out of interval loop

}


else {
    location.reload(true);
}

setTimeout(tFunction, 250);


}

setTimeout(tFunction, 250);

//setInterval("refreshPage()", 3000);
//setTimeout("twitterScan()", 100);
//setInterval(tFunction, 700);
```

Comment: Are you trying to apply this code to a web page that belongs to someone else, without writing this is their source code?  I'm not sure that that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

In the `twitterScan` method, you are trying to store element's innterHTML s which we assume are shoe names.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        tweetName[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("fullname js-action-profile-name show-popup-with-id")[0].innerHTML;
        tweet[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("js-tweet-text")[i].innerHTML;

    }
```

After, you are clicking the shoe name links if they happen to match. That looks okay, but it would be good if you let us know the flow of the whole app of yours.

From what you have said, your app code is not matching any shoe names, but is reloading your page itself. Then, it is not matching any elements with those class names. **Where exactly are the elements mentioned in your script?**

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for a twitter scanner. Rather easy. It's mostly document.getElement